# css margin in jquerymobile 1.3 button input

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

http://jsbin.com/olecad/3/edit

I am trying to move a input button by css margin-left:50%

but the button didn't move, the background moved.

Please help to guide me how to move a input button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove css from the `input` and add `css` for below.

```
.ui-btn-left, .ui-btn-right, .ui-input-clear, .ui-btn-inline, .ui-grid-a .ui-btn, .ui-grid-b .ui-btn, .ui-grid-c .ui-btn, .ui-grid-d .ui-btn, .ui-grid-e .ui-btn, .ui-grid-solo .ui-btn {
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

in `jquery.mobile.css` line number `2177`.

Comment: by the way, is there any way to move by an id not overriding the .ui-grid-c .ui-btn ?

Comment: @LeoChen use css3 parent child selector **example**  `#buttons_3 > div.ui-btn { margin-left:50% !important; }`

Comment: @LeoChen or `#buttons_3 > div.ui-btn:first-child { margin-left:50% !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS : add `text-align:center` in `button3` css and remove `margin-left:50%` from `input`

```
#buttons_1{
  background:red;
}
#buttons_2{
  background:green;
}
#buttons_3{
  background:blue;
  text-align:center;
}
#input{
        margin-top:0px;
        background:red;
    }
```

Comment: thanks Devang, but what I need is to move the button by margin-left:50%, so it will not be centered to the grid.